# C# anonymously implement interface (or abstract class)

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

In Java it is possible to extend an interface with an anonymous class that you can implement on the fly. Example:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() { /**/ }
}
```

(More on: http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2009/08/anonymous-classes-in-java.html#ixzz1k07mVIeO)

Is this possible in **C#**? If not, what are viable alternatives without having to rely on implementing a plethora of subclasses?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you can't do that in C# - but *typically* the alternative design approach is to use a delegate instead. In the example you've given, `Runnable` is usually represented using `ThreadStart`, and you can use an anonymous method or lambda expression:

```
ThreadStart start = () =>
{
    // Do stuff here
};
```

Or if you just have a method to run, with the right signature, you can use a method group conversion:

```
ThreadStart start = MethodToRunInThread;
```

Or in the `Thread` constructor call:

```
Thread t = new Thread(MethodToRunInThread);
t.Start();
```

If you *really* need to implement an interface, you'll have to really implement it (possibly in a private nested class). However, that doesn't come up terribly often in C#, in my experience - normally C# interfaces are the kind which would naturally demand a "real" implementation anyway, even in Java.

Comment: This is a feature I miss from time to time, especially because my interfaces are often narrow (role interfaces) and adhere to the Interface Segregation Principle. It would be convenient when I could register a delegate in my DI configuration, while the rest of the application could still depend on that interface (instead of a `Func<T>`), without having to create some sort of proxy class that wraps that delegate and implement that interface.

Answer (score 8):

As Jon pointed out this is not possible in C#.

One alternate pattern in C# though is to use a combination of a factory and a delegate to allow on the fly implementations of an interface.  Essentially the factory takes in a delegate for each method of the interface and uses them as the backing implementation.  For example, here's a version for `IComparable<T>`.

```
public static class ComparableFactory {
  private sealed ComparableImpl<T> : IComparable<T> {
    internal Func<T, T, int> _compareFunc;
    public int Compare(T left, T right) {
      return _compareFunc(left, right);
    }
  }
  public IComparable<T> Create<T>(Func<T, T, int> compareFunc) {
    return new ComparableImpl<T>() { _compareFunc = compareFunc };
  }
}

...

IComparable<Person> impl = CompareableFactory.Create<Person>(
  (left, right) => left.Age.CompareTo(right.Age));
```

Comment: Very cool, +1! But as a good practice, better to just roll the named class..