# Interface-implementing anonymous class in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-class

Is there a construct in C# which allows you to create a anonymous class implementing an interface, just like in Java?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface

Comment: You're confusing lambda expressions (anonymous functions) with anonymous classes. It makes no sense for a function to implement interfaces

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As has already been stated, no, this is not possible.  However, you can make a class that implements the desired interface and accepts a lambda in it's constructor so that you can turn a lambda into a class that implements the interface.  Example:

```
public class LambdaComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _lambdaComparer;
    private readonly Func<T, int> _lambdaHash;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer) :
        this(lambdaComparer, EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode)
    {
    }

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer,
        Func<T, int> lambdaHash)
    {
        if (lambdaComparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaComparer");
        if (lambdaHash == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaHash");

        _lambdaComparer = lambdaComparer;
        _lambdaHash = lambdaHash;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _lambdaComparer(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _lambdaHash(obj);
    }
}
```

Usage (obviously doing nothing helpful, but you get the idea)

```
var list = new List<string>() { "a", "c", "a", "F", "A" };
list.Distinct(new LambdaComparer<string>((a,b) => a == b));
```

Comment: Ooh, a little bit fancy!

Comment: this is the best solution for this problem i have seen yet, genius

Comment: very cool solution. The main drawback is you have to create a base class for every interface. Is there any simple way to make it generic?

Comment: @LouisRhys Simple, no.  You'd need to create the new concrete type at compile time by emitting the IL code for it directly.  It would be be fairly difficult to do.

Comment: +1. Similar to solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8941871/661933

Comment: @nawfal Yeah, the pattern has been floating around for a while.  I've seen it used a number of times in various places.

Answer (score 6):

No. C# doesn't support anonymous classes (except anonymous types which can't define methods).

Answer (score 2):

No, a Lambda Expression can not implement any additional interfaces than it already does.

You're also comparing the wrong things. I'm guessing you really meant to ask if anonymous types in C# can implement interfaces. The answer to that is also no.