# Call Linq GroupBy with IEqualityComparer on dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic-linq, dynamicquery

I want to create a dynamic GroupBy implementation that ignores case. I am using `Expression.Call`, which allows me to pass Expressions as arguments.

There are several answers on how to create a custom comparer, but this question is about how to pass a comparer dynamically.

Here is the complete method:

```
public static IQueryable GroupBy(this IQueryable source, string keySelector, string elementSelector, params object[] values)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
    if (elementSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("elementSelector");
    LambdaExpression keyLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, keySelector, false, values);
    LambdaExpression elementLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, elementSelector, false, values);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), 
            "GroupBy", 
            new Type[] { source.ElementType, keyLambda.Body.Type, elementLambda.Body.Type },
            source.Expression, 
            Expression.Quote(keyLambda), 
            Expression.Quote(elementLambda)
        )
    );
}
```

The call to `Queryable.GroupBy` is created by:

```
Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "GroupBy", 
  new Type[] { source.ElementType, keyLambda.Body.Type, elementLambda.Body.Type },
  source.Expression, Expression.Quote(keyLambda), Expression.Quote(elementLambda))
```

[`Queryable.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__3_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2___System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__) allows to pass a custom `IEqualityComparer`. How can I do this? `Expression.Call` only allows me to pass arguments of type `Expression`.

Is there any other way I can group with case ignored, by e.g. dynamically overriding `GetHashCode()` of the keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [writing a custom comparer for linq groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733773/writing-a-custom-comparer-for-linq-groupby)

Comment: @FerasAlSous The issue here is that I am creating a call to GroupBy dynamically. This is not about implementing the comparer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringComparer` can not be used here because the type is dynamic and not string. I had to elaborate on Krzysztofs answer to find a solution that worked.

First create an instance of a custom dynamic comparer `DynamicCaseInsensitiveComparer<T>` (which implements IEqualityComparer) of the same type as `keyLambda.Body.Type`. Since the type is provided by a variable, you have to use `MakeGenericType`. Then add it in the GroupBy call:

```
var comparerType = typeof(DynamicCaseInsensitiveComparer<>).MakeGenericType(keyLambda.Body.Type);
var keyComparer = Activator.CreateInstance(comparerType);

return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "GroupBy", 
        new Type[] { source.ElementType, keyLambda.Body.Type, elementLambda.Body.Type },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(keyLambda),
        Expression.Quote(elementLambda),
        Expression.Constant(keyComparer)
    )
);
```

How to create a custom comparer has been answered in other questions, see for example [IEqualityComparer for Annoymous Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934419/iequalitycomparer-for-annoymous-type)

Answer (score 1):

You should call it the same way, as you would normally by adding comparer in `GroupBy` call:

```
return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "GroupBy", 
        new Type[] { source.ElementType, keyLambda.Body.Type, elementLambda.Body.Type },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(keyLambda),
        Expression.Quote(elementLambda),
        Expression.Constant(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I do that, I get an exception `No generic method 'GroupBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.`

Comment: You need to provide more code if you want some help on that. For my test case this code worked.

Comment: I think the issue here is that I have a type that is determined at run-time, while `StringComparer` only works with `string`. The type in `keyLambda.Body.Type` at run-time is something like `DynamicClass2`

Comment: It might be it, but ignore case grouping make sense only for strings if you think about it, so maybe you try to add condition and pass comparer for strings only.

Comment: I am using LINQ to SQL. The strings are in the dynamic class. What I can do is `var comparerType = typeof(DynamicComparer<>).MakeGenericType(keyLambda.Body.Type);
            var keyComparer = Activator.CreateInstance(comparerType);` and then `Expression.Constant(keyComparer)`

Comment: Then I have to come up with a comparer that resolves the dynamic class and compares strings with `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. But only if the query is done locally (because SQL is case insensitive).